# Django occupying more memory with every request

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Many views of my Django app use a big model (900Mb) to compute their outputs. I want to load this model once and share it with all the views. The way I have done it was to load the model in `views.py` and then use the model as a global variable.

```
with open('big_model.pkl','rb') as f:
  model = pickle.load(f)

def view1(request):
  out = model.compute(request)
  ...

def view2(request):
  out = model.compute(request)
  ...
```

I have my Django app deployed on AWS beanstalk. If I run `top` on the instance running my app I see the following after 1 request:

```
Mem:   4048016k total,  2807496k used,  1240520k free,     3660k buffers
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                        
11530 wsgi      20   0 2817m 1.6g  30m S  0.0 41.9   0:04.63 httpd
```

After the second request, another process appears and 1Gb of memory got occupied.

```
Mem:   4048016k total,  3941208k used,   106808k free,     2192k buffers
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                        
11530 wsgi      20   0 2817m 1.6g  29m S  0.0 41.9   0:04.63 httpd                          
11532 wsgi      20   0 2817m 1.6g  29m S  0.0 41.9   0:04.32 httpd
```

This doesn't happen in my local machine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This module level global is shared state within the process. Locally using `runserver` you will have a single process with multiple threads. On EB you likely have multiple independent processes each with their own copy. You aren't controlling which process will handle each incoming request. The memory usage shouldn't continue increase with every request but rather should max out when each process has created its copy on import. You could limit the concurrency of your WSGI server to have a single process with multiple threads (how would depend on which WSGI server you are using). This would reduce your memory usage but also your site capacity/performance.